# How to shorten json data in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

So, I have a table (Using postgres v9) that has an id(integer) and a json(text). This is the query that I use to fetch it:

```
select software_json from software_master where id=1;
```

And I get

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "name": "C#",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "JAVA",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "JAVASCRIPT",
      "value": "3"
    },
    {
      "name": "PHP",
      "value": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "PYTHON",
      "value": "5"
    },
    {
      "name": "TSQL",
      "value": "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the output to have less records and still be a json

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "name": "C#",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "JAVA",
      "value": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, if there are more than 100 values, I want to fetch only 100 records in json format. How do I do it?

Comment: Note that all Postgres 9.x versions (9.1, 9.2, 93. 9.4, 9.5 and 9.6) are no  longer supported. If you need modern, up-to-date JSON support you should upgrade to Postgres 13 or 14. With Postgres 9.1 this is nearly impossible to solve as it did not even support any JSON at all.

Comment: Ok. If I have Postgres 13 or 14, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To select the 100 first jsonb objects in a jsonb array :

```
select jsonb_build_object('Result', jsonb_agg(j.data))
  from software_master 
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(software_json :: jsonb -> 'Result') WITH ORDINALITY AS j(data, rank)
 where id = 1
   and j.rank <= 100
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pick the first two entries from the array you can use something like this:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
         'Result', 
         jsonb_path_query_array(software_json, '$.Result[*] ? (@.value == "1" || @.value == "2")')
       )
from software_master
```

It would be easier if the values wasn't stored as a string, then you could use e.g. `'$.Result[*] ? (@.value <= 2)'`

This assumes that `software_json` is defined as a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `software_json::jsonb`

Comment: So, if I have 500 records and I only want 100, I can't use @.value <= 100 if the data type is string?

Comment: jsonb path language has only been introduced in pg v12, so `jsonb_path_query_array` is not yet available in pg v9. Should use `jsonb_array_elements` instead to break down the jsonb array and then `jsonb_agg` to rebuild it.

Comment: @Edouard: jsonb_array_elements wasn't available in 9.1 either - but ritwik1711 said in the comments to the question that they were happy with a solution for 13 or 14 as well